# Use of global NPM modules / Command not found

Tags: command-line, bash, npm

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and I have an issue using npm modules from the command line.

Actually I installed `sequelize` and `sequelize-cli` and when I try to run their commands the terminal tells me that the **command was not found**. I also tried installing it globally testwise, but did not work either.

> echo $PATH
>   /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/ole/.npm:/home/ole/.npm/lib/node_modules

Note that I manually added `/home/ole/.npm:/home/ole/.npm/lib/node_module` to `$PATH` since this is the location where my global packages got installed. What am I missing here?

Thank you very much and merry christmas!

**Edit:** When I remove everything except `/usr/bin` from `$PATH` it works, but then i cannot use other programs like nano anymore. If I add multiple Paths it is again not working....